# Parse.com query and application design issue: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, parse-platform

In my **iOS** app I need to retrieve some values by using `PFObject` queries. And when these are all loaded, the app should continue doing some more stuff.

```
func processTransaction(){

   .. some code to prepare my 2 queries

   var balance1 = balance1Query.getFirstObject() as PFObject;
   var balance2 = balance2Query.getFirstObject() as PFObject;

   .. after these are loaded i have to update them, and 'release' the screen to the user. 
}
```

Now, when using this `.getFirstObject()` method, I get a warning in my **Xcode** debug window saying:

> A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.

Of course I did some research, and every answer I read talks about using 
`getObjectInBackgroundWithId`, which then moves the execution of these queries to the background (I guess doing so it puts them on a new thread.)

But my question is, how should I structure my code / design, to make sure that both objects are loaded, before the code continues to work with these objects?

I tried some things, and create some code like below, but to me it feels like this isn't the right approach. Can't think of what a mess this will become when I have to load and make sure that 4 or 5 objects are loaded.

```
balanceQuery1.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (balance1: PFObject!, error1: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error1 == nil {
        balanceQuery2.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (balance2: PFObject!, error2: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error2 == nil {
                ... processing here..
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that is the right approach. Just remember to dispatch any code that updates your UI back on the main queue. for balanceQuery2 you can just use getFirstObject as you already off the main queue

Comment: Hm.. alright. Thanks for your reply. But, i'm still wondering, is there no other way than nesting, and nesting, and even more nesting?   In .NET i have Waits, and i can chain tasks (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610(v=vs.110).aspx). Isn't there something similar to this available in iOS/Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion that your approach was correct was based on the requirement to execute two queries - In this case you can dispatch the first query into the background and then execute the subsequent query in the completion block.

If you are looking for a more general asynchronous dispatch model then I would suggest using dispatch groups to synchronise the activities.  To use this technique effectively it is best to have your queries in an array or similar data structure. (Apologies, I haven't converted this to Swift, but it is essentially the same)

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

// Add a task to the group

for (int i=0;i<self.queries.count;i++) {


    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
       self.queries[i].getFirstObject ...
    });
}

// When you cannot make any more forward progress,
// wait on the group to block the current thread.
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// Release the group when it is no longer needed.
dispatch_release(group);
```

Comment: Thanks, i can use this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid nesting, there is a second approach that can be useful, especially if you have a LOT of queries to run. Three steps:

1. Set an `int completedQueries` variable to 0 that will be incremented when a query finishes
2. Set an `int totalQueries` variable that represents the total number of queries to finish
3. For each query's completion block, increment `completedQueries` and run a function to check if the number of completions is equal to the total:

   ```
   balanceQuery1.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
       (balance1: PFObject!, error1: NSError!) -> Void in
       if error1 == nil {
           completedQueries++
           checkQueriesCompleted()
       }
   }
   //balanceQuery2, 3 and so on below...
   ```

Finally, have a `checkCompletedQueries` function that waits until your total and completed are equal:

```
func checkQueriesCompleted() {
    if (completedQueries == totalQueries) {
        //... processing here ....
    }
}
```

This structure is especially powerful if you have 3+ functions, or you have an arbitrary number of calls. I use it a lot when I want to get around the 1000 item return limit on Parse (get a total number of objects, make as many calls as I need with a .skip parameter, wait for all returns before processing) - you get the idea.

Comment: And, i must say, this looks like an interesting idea as well!